# Ruby dynamic lambda with static method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I'm writing Rails concern, and need to run something like

```
class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base 
  @base = 'awesome'
  has_many :comments, ->() { where(have_#{@_base} => true) }
end
```

but lambda will be executed in `Comment` context. I've made hack with `eval "has_many :comments, ->() { where(have_#{@_base} => true) }"`.

Is there any way to use this functionality without `eval`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with [BasicObject#`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) (it allows you to pass argument to the block):

```
class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base 
  @base = 'awesome'
  instance_exec(@base) do |arg|
    has_many :comments, -> { where("have_#{arg}" => true) }
  end
end
```